# python function argument mismatch

Tags: python, function

I am defining the below function.

```
def trip_cost(days, city):
    return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

However, when it executes I receive the below error:

```
trip_cost('Pittsburgh', 8) raised an error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

But, if I execute the below code;

```
def trip_cost(city,days):
    return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

It runs fine.

the complete code is provided below;

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
      return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
      if city == "Charlotte":
         return 183
      elif city == "Tampa":
         return 220
      elif city == "Pittsburgh":
         return 222
      elif city == "Los Angeles":
         return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
      cost = days * 40
          if days >= 7:
               cost -= 50
          elif days >= 3:
               cost -= 20
          return cost

def trip_cost(days, city):
        return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Comment: fix your indentation in `rental_car_cost`, this may be the issue

Comment: You are multiplying string  40 times "cost = days * 40".  days == "Pittsburgh"

Comment: You have the arguments the wrong way around for the first example i.e. you are assigning `"Pittsburg"` to the variable `days`

Comment: Your function signature says it all. `hotel_cost` should be passed a number, `plane_ride_cost` a string, `rental_car_cost` should be passed a  number. `trip_cost(city, days) = hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)` satisfies the arguments passed to all 3 functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the function is expecting first argument to be an integer, but you are passing a str in the place of it.

A clever way to handle such cases would be to pass object which might look like this: `{'city':'Pittsburgh', 'days':10}`

Answer (score 0):

The Code works fine:

call trip_cost(days,city) ie (8,'Pittsburgh') instead of ('Pittsburgh',8)

example:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
      return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
      if city == "Charlotte":
         return 183
      elif city == "Tampa":
         return 220
      elif city == "Pittsburgh":
         return 222
      elif city == "Los Angeles":
         return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
      cost = days * 40
      if days >= 7:
           cost -= 50
      elif days >= 3:
           cost -= 20
      return cost

def trip_cost(days, city):
        return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
print trip_cost(4,'Tampa')
```

Output:920

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are passing a string 'Pittsburg' to days and 8 to the city in the first one. Hence the first function hotel_cost returns a string and the second function plane_ride_cost returns nothing since none of its cases match to 8. Hence it returns the NoneType object and can't append to the string object returned.

So the best practice while passing arguments to a function is listing down the parameters and then passing the value, something like this. :

```
trip_cost(days = 8 , city = 'Pittsburgh')
```